# Is there a Custom Elements polyfill targeting Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, web-component, polyfills, custom-element

I'm trying to use Custom Elements in my app and have it be compatible across all browsers (Chrome, Safari, Opera, FireFox, IE). I've transpiled the code from ES6 to ES5 with Babel.

I looked into Polyfills and was able to make the site work locally on all the browsers except for Internet Explorer, by using the following:

```
<script src="../node_modules/webcomponents.js/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/@webcomponents/shadydom/shadydom.min.js"></script>
script src="../node_modules/@webcomponents/custom-elements/custom-elements.min.js"></script>
```

I've looked into https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element and the custom elements es5 adapter but IE never works and some of the other working browsers will break.

I've been testing IE through the Cross Browser Testing site and I couldn't see any error messages upon inspecting.

Comment: Did you read https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element/issues/97

Answer (score 1):

what elements are you using?

adding https://www.npmjs.com/package/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs via

`<script src="node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>`

works just fine in IE11 if the component is using only stuff that is supported...

However, most likely your components are written in ES6 meaning they will need to be transpired by something like babel.

If you have a simple component you can just test it via pasting the code here https://babeljs.io/repl/ and then serve the result to IE11.

Most likely you will want to have a build step for your application that does that automatically.
Or for development, you could just use `npm i -g polymer-cli` and do `polymer serve` which will transpile the code automatically if needed. (and it will also do differential serving e.g. serve es6 to browsers that support it (like chrome) and es5 to browsers that don't support it (like IE11))

Answer (score 0):

Was experiencing a similar issue.

The solution was to load `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.5.7/core.min.js` before the other polyfills.

(Am using `webcomponents-loader.js`)

Also note that scripts seem to be INTERPRETED at the time of load (time after when `.src` is set) but not RUN until appended to the document. -- So make sure you don't start loading dependent libraries until the necessary polyfills are loaded, because even if the script is not run/appended yet, it will still tell you e.g. `customElements is not defined`.